# apex code coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

kindly let me know to resolve the following test class issue.

apex:-

```
public void associateLanguageAndCountry(String userId, Country_Language__c countryLanguage){
    User user = [SELECT ContactId
                 FROM User
                 WHERE Id =: userId];

    if(user != null){
        Contact contact = [Select AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Id =: user.ContactId];
    }
}
```

Test class:-

```
String email1 = 'testUtil@test.on.ca';
Account oAccount = TestUtility.createAccount(email1,'Person Account', false);

Contact oContact1 = TestUtility.createContact(oAccount.Id,'vineet','srivast',false);
UserRole ur1 = new UserRole(Name ='CEO');
insert ur1;
Profile prof2 = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Tier 1']; 
User oUser = new User(Alias = 'standt12', Email='vineet@zensar.com',contactId=oContact1.Id,
        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', firstname='test',
        LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = prof2.Id,Site__c='Logitech', userroleid = ur1.Id,
        TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName=Math.random()+'@'+Math.random());

insert oUser ;
system.runas(oUser){

    contact c= new contact();
    c.firstname='vineet';                 
    c.lastname='sri';
    insert c;
    user ous=[select id,contactId,AccountId from user where id=:oUser.Id]; 

    contact con =[select AccountId from contact where id=:ous.contactId];

    SupportContactDetailController scdc = new SupportContactDetailController();

    scdc.associateLanguageAndCountry(oUser.Id,countrylangobject);


}
```

Test class is failing in apex at this line

```
  Contact contact = [Select AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Id =: user.ContactId];
```

Comment: I don't understand where your `associateLanguageAndCountry()` method. Also, in your test class, it looks like you don't assign the contact id to the newly created user.

Comment: @Martin. thnx for ur reply.It was added in the class but here i have not called let me edit it. Regrading contact id , i think ihave used contactid field while creating user.

Comment: What is the error message you are receiving when your test class is failing?

Comment: @khushboo. thankx. it says list has no rows for assignment.

Comment: Make sure `Contact oContact1=TestUtility.createContact` inserts contact into the system

Comment: List has no rows means that the query is returning no data that can be assigned to Contact con. Backtracking it shows that User ous is not returning ContactId. That is Contact data is not committed and you are using it. So, add insert oContact1 after you have initialized  oContact1. Let me know if this doesn't works!

Comment: @khushboo ,rohit you are correct but i checked in utility class. itz inserting contact. so, there is no need to insert it again in test class. if i create a new contact instead of claling from utility.itz giving mixed dml error

Answer (score 0):

In your test class create test data with the contact associated with user then it wont fail since the user is linked with contact

```
    Set<String> customerUserTypes = new Set<String> {'CSPLiteUser', 'PowerPartner', 'PowerCustomerSuccess',   'CustomerSuccess'};
Account acc = new Account (
                            Name = 'newAcc1'
                            );  
insert acc;
Contact con = new Contact (AccountId = acc.id,LastName = 'portalTestUser');
insert con;

Profile p = [select Id,name from Profile where UserType in :customerUserTypes limit 1];

User newUser = new User(
                    profileId = p.id,
                    username = 'newUser@yahoo.com',
                    email = 'pb@ff.com',
                    emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8',
                    localesidkey = 'en_US',
                    languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
                    timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                    alias='nuser',
                    lastname='lastname',
                    contactId = con.id
                );
insert newUser;
```

Your test class is something like this

```
 String email1 = 'testUtil@test.on.ca';
         Account oAccount = TestUtility.createAccount(email1,'Person Account', false);

         Contact oContact1=TestUtility.createContact(oAccount.Id,'vineet','srivast',false);
           Id currentUserID = UserInfo.getUserId();
           system.runas([Select Id from User where ID = :currentUserID])
           {
                UserRole ur1 = new UserRole(Name ='CEO');
                insert ur1;
                Profile prof2 = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Tier 1']; 
                User oUser = new User(Alias = 'standt12', Email='vineet@zensar.com',contactId=oContact1.Id,
                EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', firstname='test',
                LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = prof2.Id,Site__c='Logitech', userroleid = ur1.Id,
                TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName=Math.random()+'@'+Math.random());
                 insert oUser ;
            }        


            contact c= new contact();
            c.firstname='vineet';                 
            c.lastname='sri';
            insert c;
            user ous=[Select id,contactId from user where Alias= :standt12]; 
            contact con =[select AccountId from contact where id=:ous.contactId];
            SupportContactDetailController scdc = new SupportContactDetailController();
            scdc.associateLanguageAndCountry(oUser.Id,countrylangobject);
```